# How to reset the admin password for Observium

Tags: network-monitoring, system-monitoring, observium

How can i reset the password for the user `admin` with MySQL or a Observium script.

```
MariaDB [observium]> select * from users;
+---------+----------+------------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+
| user_id | username | password                           | realname | email | descr | level | can_modify_passwd | user_options |
+---------+----------+------------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+
|       1 | admin    | $1$abcdefgh$jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd. |          |       |       |    10 |                 1 | NULL         |
+---------+----------+------------------------------------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like it MD5 (1) hash with salt (abcdefgh).

`openssl passwd -1` build new hash from plain password

You can use it to update users table.

You can try build Mysql-only solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903702/md5-and-salt-in-mysql

But salt must be cryptographic quality random for secyrity.

**UPD.**

Blackbox Hacking solution. Copy password field from other user with known password, event from different instance of observium.
It work 99%

Comment: it does not work:  `UPDATE users SET password = MD5('abcdefgh' + ':' + 'newPassword') WHERE user_id = 1;` i cant login with "newPassword"

Comment: It question which algorythm used to build hash with salt. At first try standard `openssl passwd -1` it make different value

Comment: Yes i tried `openssl passwd -1`, but i get differ results with the same password

Comment: Different values is ok. Bacause every time different random salt is used.

Comment: For debug is possible to force using specific salt `openssl passwd -1 -salt abcdefgh `, but it insecure for production.

Comment: i could not login, because i limited the ip access: `SELECT config_value FROM config WHERE config_key = 'web_session_cidr';`

Answer (score 3):

this might help someone. as it just worked for me as long as you have root access to the server

```
cd /opt/observium
./adduser.php admin <CLASS_PASSWORD> 10
```

once the new user with the same level of permission is active you can then update the other users password